# SFDMU Target Metadata Retrieval Error

Tags: metadata, data, data-migration, sfdmu

I'm receiving 2 distinct errors when trying to execute insert or upsert against my Contact object using SFDMU during and org to org script.

1. Upsert:  Each run gets to Stage 2 Target {Contact} Mapping query string ... Target object: Contact... then produces "[ERROR] Error during execution of the command: line 1:2538 extraneous input ',' expecting {GROUP, ... ,N_FISCAL_YEARS_AGO, '(', id]"
   [ERROR] Execution of the command sfdmu:run has been completed. Exit code 4 (COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR).

So I tried an insert instead, thinking I could just separate the process into Insert then Update scripts instead of Upsert since it's broken...

2. Insert:  Gets to === ANALYSING DATA... then throws this error:
   [ERROR] Error during analysing of the org metadata: The object Contact is missing in the Target..
   [ERROR] Execution of the command sfdmu:run has been completed. Exit code 3 (ORG_METADATA_ERROR).

More Info:

- I've been able to successfully run this upsert to a CSV target
  without issue.
- I haven't encountered this issue with any other target Object
- Confirmed Contact Object and Contact Metadata do in fact exist in the Target org

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I had "useCSVValueMapping": true in the object definition but no ValueMapping.csv file in the runtime directory.  In my case, I need the value mapping file so I added one to the directory and kept the setting = true which solved the problem.  Similarly tested it where I removed the setting/set it to false and it did not generate the syntax errors.